# Magento installation on Linux server

Tags: linux, magento

[image]I am facing problem when i install **Magento 1.9.3.0** on Linux server. It stuck on localization option as mentioned in screenshot. But if i install it on another local Linux server it installed properly.

Comment: can you add more detail? are the two servers the same version? was it the same exact installation method on both?

Comment: yes i installed on centos 6 and ubuntu 14.04 server, it works fine on both of..

Comment: Turn on or increase php error reporting.